# Blazor server app does not serve more than 5 new browser tabs

Tags: websocket, signalr, blazor-server-side

I have an Balzor Server application on a Windows Server 2019 (also IIS 10+) and works well, but if a client opens different pages of the application in new tabs, for more than 5 bowser tabs, pages could not be loaded. If the client close some tabs, the new ones could be open.

I guess that it may be depends on a limit about number of WebSocket or SignalR connections, or possibly some other configuration on Server.

Is there any idea, how can I solve it?